# Conditional probability using given data

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, bayesian

[image]

My work:

For part a) I have $0.14$  x $0.04= 0.0004$

For part b) I'm confused between the following two calculations.
 Would it be $0.055 + 0.023 + 0.04$ or would it be  $0.16$ x $0.055 +  0.70$ x $0.023 + 0.14$ x $0.04$?

For part c) I have $P(Over 65 | Accident)$= $\frac{answer from part (a)}{answer from part (b)}$

Can someone please clarify these? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach to (a) is correct but your computation is not.  $$0.14 \times 0.04 = 0.0056.$$  I have no idea how you got $0.0004$.

I should point out that while part (a) asks "What is the probability...accident and the driver was over 65," the **intent** should be "What is the probability...accident and the driver was **65 or over**."  The reason is that the last category of drivers includes ages 65 and over.  Otherwise, you would have insufficient information to answer the question as originally stated.

For part (b), your first calculation is incorrect because it does not weight the probability of accident by the proportion of drivers in the respective age group.  Therefore, the second calculation is the correct one.

For part (c), your approach is correct but you should explain your reasoning formally.  Let $B$ be the event a randomly selected driver is at least age $65$.  Let $A$ be the event that a randomly selected driver had an accident.  Then you are asked to compute $\Pr[B \mid A]$, the probability that, given a randomly selected driver had an accident, that this driver was at least age $65$.  By definition of conditional probability,
$$\Pr[B \mid A] = \frac{\Pr[B \cap A]}{\Pr[A]}.$$  The numerator is the joint probability that a randomly selected driver had an accident and is at least age $65$, which is the computation from part (a).  The denominator is the unconditional/marginal probability of a randomly selected driver having an accident, which is the computation from part (b).

Comment: First part was a typo, sorry! For part b, can you explain what you mean when you say "because it does not weight the probability of accident by the proportion of drivers in the respective age group." On the other hand, what DOES 0.055 + 0.023 + 0.04 represent?

Comment: @user140161 Because $70\%$ of drivers in your population are in the 25-64 age group, their contribution to the overall population's accident rate is greater than the other age groups.  If there are 10000 drivers in your population, 1600 are under 25, 7000 are 26-64, and 1400 are 65 and over.  88 of the under-25, 161 of the 25-64, and 56 of the 65-and-over, had an accident.  So even though the accident rate is higher among the oldest and youngest groups, the bulk of the accidents are in the middle age group because most of the drivers are in this group.

Comment: The overall accident rate is therefore $(88 + 161 + 56)/10000 = 0.0305$, which is the same result as if you did the weighted probability calculation.  The other calculation doesn't represent anything related to the actual population.  It would represent the overall accident probability **if all three age groups are equally represented**.